# Heap vs stack vs bss section

Tags: c, memory

What is better place to store runtime data with constant predefined size (like buffers): heap (malloc), stack (e.g. `char buf[BUFSIZE]` inside a function) or bss section (`char buf[BUFSIZE]` in the global area)?

Comment: Are you writing a compiler? or you are only querying related to software you are writing?

Comment: If you are writing your own C/C++ or JAVA program, you don't quite make such a choice on your own. (Unless you writing your own part of Assembly). Compiler does this on its own. What then is a real question? are you asking - "how to force compiler to put data in respective section?" or "whether or not compiler should do particular placement?"

Comment: @Dipan: AFAIK, C compiler doesn't choose place for data itself. Global non-initialized area is bss, local (non-static) area is stack, heap via malloc (in C99 also via variable length arrays). Isn't it?

Comment: Frankly i thought Data = BSS + Heap which is selected by compiler; and software doesn't really make choice there! OK, I got confused by this wiki page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) where in it says "Data = Data + BSS + HEAP" which doesn't fully make sense to me. you should put clarification as to what other "data" is this beyond what is not there in BSS or HEAP or Stack by default? And is there such a think that programmers need to make a choice?

Comment: @DipanMehta it is that (data + bss + heap) of ELF build up the data segment of process that this ELF will be mapped into

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the buffer.

Globals should usually be avoided, you will have to be very careful to not fall over the problems coming with them.

If the buffer is needed in only one function and BUFSIZE is not too large (a few KB max), you can make it local. However, keep an eye on total stack usage, as nested calls add up. A static local is only needed when you want to keep the values between calls, effectively making it a global with local scope. But it will give you headaches when you go multi-threading or want to use recursion.

If the buffer is used across function calls or BUFSIZE is quite large, then use malloc()/free(). If the function is called often, it may be a good idea to allocate it once outside of the function, do all the function calls, and then free it, instead of allocate and free another buffer for each function call. But this is near premature optimization, because it unnecessarily couples the internal structure of the function with the outside caller.

In the bigger picture, when your program grows, you want to give it more structure and clearly define responsibilities, esp. for memory handling, else you will eventually lose track. This buffer is a working detail of a specific module with a specific task. A typical approach is to use a struct to organize data in an OOP way, with a create and destroy function to allocate and free such an object. The buffer could then be part of this struct.

```
struct s_foo
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    ...
};

struct s_foo *foo_create (...);
void foo_destroy (struct s_foo *foo);
void foo_action (struct s_foo *foo);
```

This allows you to have any amount of foos in parallel, each with its own buffer, independent from each other. Additionally, the buffer content is kept between calls without the headaches of a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want a static variable that's allocated at load time and remains through the life of the program. So option three, the so called "bss" section.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, heap is out because the size is limited. I wouldn't go for statics either because they are not reentrant and they bring havoc in recursion. So, put it in the stack frame.

```
void f(...) {
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
}
```

BTW, its a good practice to avoid statics or globals unless they are absolutely necessary.

Comment: What if `BUFSIZE` is too big?

Comment: @user14284, stack frame is out because of the size limit. But, still no static because its life time is program life time and big-buf will eat up big memory. That only leaves malloc. Now malloc is a beast, so it has to be poached right.